# How to get post from facebook?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, facebook-graph-api

I have created the page in Facebook .I want all the posts posted in that page.And one more thing i only created the page. Please help me out . Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need the graph API.

The URL you want is https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_PAGE_NAME_OR_ID/feed?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

You can get an access token [programatically](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) or just get one from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)

More about the Graph API [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also find here the [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#feed) Page related api's...

[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=130540617023687/feed) you can test all the api's before implementing in the app..

Comment: I am using facebook graph-api only.